# xeLaTeX: Not enough room in an internal buffer

Tags: xetex

So i'm compiling and this is what it says. The documentation is extensive. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: With no MWE, this is 'too localized'.